# Get all likes and comments of all media in a hashtag

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm working on a project with huge of media and I want to get the number of likes and comments by particular hashtag every single day.
If I use Cron, I cannot get those numbers in a day (Instagram limits: 5000 requests/hour)

Any suggestions?

Comment: you can create multiple test instagram accounts and run APIs until u get http429 and switch to a different access_token and continue, but u may get banned :(

Answer (score 0):

The /media/{media-id} endpoint ([media endpoint](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/)) returns a number of total likes and comments if that's all you're after. If you want each individual like or comment, you'll need /media/{media-id}/likes ([media likes endpoint](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/)) and /media/{media-id}/comments ([media comments endpoint](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/likes/)).